# Deploying a website to windows azure with web sockets

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a node.js project that works fine on my local machine running a node server. However when I deploy it to azure I can not connect to the websocket server. I heard somewhere that you may need to edit the web.config file to turn on web sockets, but I cant find that anywhere.

The server sets up a websocket like follows:

```
var http = require('http'),
    port = process.env.port || 1337,
    NodeSimpleRouter = require('node-simple-router'),
    router = new NodeSimpleRouter(),
    WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server,
    wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8080});

    //create the server
    http.createServer(router).listen(port);
    console.log('Web server running on port ' + port);
```

and the client like this:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
```

do I need to change any of these settings, such as the value of 'localhost'?

Answer (score 0):

Azure can be a pain sometimes with websockets and node.js . Here is what I got to work using socket.io . I have my code deployed out as a cloud service. Be careful if you do VIP swaps from staging to prod because I have noticed it doesn't play nice with websockets.

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(app.get('port'));

//Chat room
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('send', function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit('message', data);

    });
});
```

You can also override the websockets and force default of long-polling by using this:

```
//Over ride the Azure defaults
io.configure(function () {
    io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]);
    io.set("polling duration", 10);
});
```